# Magnific Popup iframe auto resize on content change (cross domain)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, autoresize, magnific-popup

At the moment we are only using the iframe type of Magnific Popup (jQuery plugin). However the popup doesn't resize it's height when the content of the iframe grows/shrinks dynamically. I think for inline content resizing seems to work though.

I searched the documentation and the web but could not find any solution.

Therefore I was looking for third party solutions to auto resize (cross domain) iframes on content change.
Best I found so far (looking for a simple solution) are:

[jQuery resize event](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/) (using a Fork because the original doesn't seem to be maintained)
to be able to bind a resize event in combination with:

[jQuery postMessage](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/) (using a Fork for same reason)
to implement cross-domain communication between iframe and parent (because of same origin policy).

(Can't post links to forks since this is my first question and I'm only allowed to post two links... )

I got those working for a simple test iframe, now I want to implement this into Magnific Popup.

Just now I stumbeld upon a resize event in the documentation, which is already built into MFP: "resize event triggers only when height is changed or layout forced". However it doesnt fire when I display more/less text in the iframe based on a select input (only test so far but thats what I need at the moment).

So before implementing all those plugins I thought maybe I ask if someone already has a working solution for this or if I just overlooked a built in function/didn't use it right. I'm pretty new to JavaScript.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there doesn't seem to be a built in solution for auto resizing (non-video) iframes in Magnific Popup I built my own solution using external plugins as mentioned above.

To check if the iframe content height has changed I used [this Fork of jQuery resize event plugin](https://github.com/GerHobbelt/jquery-resize/blob/master/jquery.ba-resize.js), which is compatible with the current jQuery version 1.11.1.

To send the new height from iframe to parent window (cross domain compatible) I ended up using this [jQuery postMessage Plugin](http://vistaprint.github.io/SkinnyJS/jquery.postMessage.html), which seems to be well maintained and works in IE6+.

Also I switched to use "type: inline" of Magnific Popup to display the iframes, since "type: iframe" seems to be specificaly styled for iframe video embedding like YouTube videos, which made it hard for me to style the popup height in a simple way.

There might be a cleaner/straight forward solution, that's why I didn't get into too much details. Another reason is that I used quite a few lines of code for implementation into MFP and since I'm new to JS it might not be the best code ;)
But since there was no answer yet I will mark this as accepted answer for now because it works.

Best solution of course would be if Magnific Popup would have a built in solution (feature request!).

Comment: What also helped a lot as a starter was this [example of iframe resizing](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-postmessage/examples/iframe/). However be aware that he uses his own jQuery postMessage plugin, which is not compatible with the current jQuery verison. Had to post this as comment since I still can only post 2 Links per Post...

Comment: Oliver, I have edited my answer. If you use https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer, it should help you out. I also noticed that magnific has a **resize** callback, which allows you to ignore the origin of the iframe. I have implemented this solution on my webstore, and so far it has worked seamlessly. Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can use: https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

This requires that you add a script to the page loading the `<iframe>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../iframeResizer.min.js"></script>
```

As well as to the **external** page you are trying to load Inside of the `<iframe>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js"></script>
```

Note: If you are trying to load an external domain which isn't yours, this may not work for you - because you must have a script added in both places (sorry), but this WILL work if you are trying to load an HTTPS page inside a NON HTTPS page.

I also define my own markup for the magnific popup in the script.

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.open-popup').magnificPopup({
            items: {src: '/file.html'},
            type: 'iframe',
              iframe: {
                 markup: '<div class="iframe-popup">'+
                            '<iframe class="mfp-iframe" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen></iframe>'+
                            '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
                          '</div>'
              },
        });
      });
```

You can resize the width of the iframe pretty easily with CSS to 100% of the parent window... as long as you have a `max-width` set on your parent (`.iframe-popup` in the example above).

One major thing I figured out that magnific actually has a **resize** callback included in its code:

```
    callbacks: {
        resize: function() {
            $('iframe').iFrameResize([{
                enablePublicMethods: true,
                checkOrigin: false
            }]);
         }
```

That's it. Works for me every time.

Comment: Nice small code but it doesn't seem to work cross domain (same origin policy). Also it depends on onload, so it wouldn't work if the iframe content changes without reload (e.g. Ajax)?

Comment: I think not checking the origin when using PostMessage is a security risk. See "Security concerns" here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage
However thanks for the update! When I did my research I was checking this iframe risizer script too, but didn't use it for some reason, maybe because it's IE8+ and originally our project still had to support IE7 (not anymore though). The solution I posted is IE6+ and works fine for me too. But I have to say your code is much(!) smaller, I'll try (with checking origin) when I got some time left, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the solution to this and only found a simple solution for non-cross domain communication without using a plugin. (I haven't tested cross-domain, but I can't say it won't work).

There's a way for iframes to inherently communicate with their parent's window. You can resize the parent via this code on your iframe

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // access the iframe's parent in order to resize
        var contentHeight           = $('.your-iframe-wrapper').height(),
            parentBody              = window.parent.document.body;          

        $('iframe', parentBody).animate({
            height: contentHeight + 100,
            maxHeight : "100%"
        }, 200)     

    });

</script>
```

When your iFrame loads, it should run this script, and access the iFrame's parent window and resize it from there. Hope this helps someone out.

Comment: Even smaller code, looks good :) (not tested myself). Sadly this won't work with cross domain iframes either, since you can't access window.parent cross domain. Yes, I didn't ask  for a cross domain solution as a must have in my question, but I would need it. I will update my question.